# "grab" tag doesn't mean anything

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[grab](/questions/tagged/grab) is used for various things. Burninate?

"grab" can mean extracting a frame of video, downloading a file, capturing the mouse pointer, etc..

Comment: It's a synonym of **grope**

Comment: I just looked at the 40 questions having this tag, and I think they don't need it - nor any replacement.

Comment: Agreed; this is a meaningless tag that doesn't deserve to exist.